# Can't stop or prevent apache server from launching on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, apache, startup, launch, macos-catalina

I have searched and tried a lot of solutions here and all over Google. My situation is as follows.

I just don't want Apache to be running.

1) localhost leads to "It works!" page
2) The command `sudo apachectl stop` results in:

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

3) `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` leads to the same output as in the number 2.

Comment: What do you have in your `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`? I seem to recall this is a text (XML?) file.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you happen to install Apache with brew? I did and forgot about it. For me, I had to unload the user plist file `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` and then `brew service cleanup` to delete the plist (install `brew tap homebrew/services` if services isn't installed).

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue, based on [this guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions) the following worked for me:

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: How can this be undone / onboard Apache re-enabled?